# Wordpress breadcrumbs issue

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb in my website that's not working properly.
When I go to a product like

`Equipment» Products» Railing» Heavy Railing» Waterproof» Superrail 2000`

it shows me this breadcrumb properly as it should. However when I get to the same product through "Non-waterproof" instead of "Waterproof" it shows me this same breadcrumb (so basicly, it only follows 1 category).

I wanted to check this in the settings of my breadcrumb plugin, but it shows me the message "Your settings are out of date. Migrate now.", and my supervisor has adviced me to not "migrate" it.

Does anyone have a solution that uses either a plugin or custom code that works with multiple categories?

**Edit:**

I'm working with WP 3.6, which I'm not allowed to update.
The URL looks something like this http://www.website.com/product/asl6109t32/, which means I can't use the URL to generate the breadcrumb.

Comment: Try this: https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 1):

If I may, here is some nifty code snippet for creating breadcrumb navigation, place it in your theme's`functions.php` file:

```
/*********************************************************** 
* wsf_breadcrumbs() - Shows breadcrumbs in template 
***********************************************************/  
function wsf_breadcrumbs( $sep = '/', $label = 'Browsing' ) {  

    global $post, $front_page;  

   // Do not show breadcrumbs on home or front pages.  
   // So we will just return quickly  
   if((is_home() || is_front_page()) && (!$front_page))  
      return;  

    // Create a constant for the separator, with space padding.  
    $SEP = ' ' . $sep . ' ';  

  echo '<div class="breadcrumbs">';  
  echo $label;  
  echo wsf_make_link( home_url(), 'Home', get_bloginfo('name'), true ) . $SEP;  

  if(is_single()) {  
    the_category(', '); echo $SEP;   
  } 
    elseif (is_search()) {
        echo 'Search results - ';
    } 
    elseif (is_404()) { //Wordpress bug
        echo 'Error 404 (Page not found) '; 
    }
    elseif (is_author()) {
        echo 'Articles posted by author ';
    }
    elseif (is_tag()) { 
        echo 'Posts tagged ';
    }
    elseif (is_year()) {
        echo get_the_time('Y');
    }
  elseif (is_month()) {
        echo get_the_time('F').' ('.get_the_time('Y').')';
    }

    elseif (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"wp-login.php")) {
        echo 'Administration panel';
    }


    elseif(is_page()) {  
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;  
        $parents = array();  
        while($parent_id) {  
                $page = get_page($parent_id);  
        $parents[]  = wsf_make_link( get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID) ) . $SEP;  
                $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;  
        }  
        $parents = array_reverse($parents);  
    foreach($parents as $parent) {  
       echo $parent;  
    }  
  }  
   // Wordpess function that echoes your post title.  
  the_title();  
  echo '</div>';  
}  
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Create breadcrumb navigation
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
/*********************************************************** 
* Helper Functions for template coding 
***********************************************************/  
function wsf_make_link ( $url, $anchortext, $title=NULL, $nofollow=false ) {  
   if ( $title == null ) $title=$anchortext;  
   $rel = ($nofollow == true) ? ' rel="nofollow"' : $rel = '';   

   $link = sprintf( '<a href="%s" title="%s" %s>%s</a>', $url, $title, $rel, $anchortext );  
   return $link;   
}  

/*------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Then, in your `footer.php` file, invoke the function like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
 <?php wsf_breadcrumbs('','') ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Will this show me the category if the url doesn't include it?

Comment: I have implemented this and all it shows me is `Home ASL6109T/32`.

Comment: The pages/posts must be properly set, i.e. to have proper `parent` in order breadcrumb navigation to work.

Comment: How will it know through which parent I've reached the page? I need to set multiple categories.

Comment: `foreach($parents as $parent) {  echo $parent;  }`, it goes through all parents, see the code.

Comment: Alright but how can I give a page multiple parents?

Comment: Well, this is not possible in Wordpress, but you can add categories to the page, as many as you want

Comment: And how would I get this category to appear in the breadcrumb after reaching the product through that specific category?